# Ansible Loop over dictionaries and lists

Tags: ansible

I have a variable file which is in following format:

```
files:
   name: file1
   size: 50K
   location:
     - /var/tmp
     - /nfsvol
     - /tmp
    users:
     - user1
     - user2
     - user3
```

I want task file to be generated in a following way using some loop over dictionaries and lists and it can be passed to playbook:

```
- name: Build File Repo
  file_repo:
     name: file1
     size: 50K
     location:
       - user1
       - user2
       - user3
     users:
       - /var/tmp
       - /nfs_vol
       - /tmp
```

The var files can contain many blocks of "files "and I want task file to go through the entire var file using a loop specified in a task file so that each block can be executed on the specified hosts.

Var files can be like this:

```
files:
   name: file1
   size: 50K
   location:
     - /var/tmp
     - /nfsvol
     - /tmp
    users:
     - user1
     - user2
     - user3

files:
   name: file2
   size: 53K
   location:
     - /var/tmp
     - /nfsvol
   users:
     - user5
     - user21
```

I tried with sub element and also followed the following  thread but it does not meet my purpose;
[Nested loop with a list and a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983741/nested-loop-with-a-list-and-a-dictionary?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to

> To go through the entire var file using a loop specified in a task

where

> var files can contain many blocks of "files"

It's not possible to have "many" variables named "files". Put all "blocks" to a list and *loop: "{{ files }}"*

```
files:
  - name: file1
    size: 50K
    location:
      - /var/tmp
      - /nfsvol
      - /tmp
    users:
      - user1
      - user2
      - user3
  - name: file2
    size: 53K
    location:
      - /var/tmp
      - /nfsvol
    users:
      - user5
      - user21
```

The task below is probably what you want.

```
tasks:
  - name: Touch files
    file:
      path: "{{ item.1 }}/{{ item.0.name }}"
      state: touch
    loop: "{{ lookup('subelements', files, 'location') }}"
```

Comment: I agree as I tried many methods to workout the above requirement as the file is coming as an automated output and I need to pass the file to a task to execute the playbook. I will write one small interface to convert the file into required format.