# Ansible: Nested loop with dictionary & dynamic list : 'item' is undefined" Error

Tags: ansible, jinja2

The requirement was to get a dynamic set of files from a directory based on a dictionary. I've implemented it with concept mentioned in: [Nested loop with a list and a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983741/nested-loop-with-a-list-and-a-dictionary)

```
    - name: color print - hardcoded
      debug:
        msg:
        - "{{ item[0] }} - {{ item[1] }}"
      with_nested:
        - [ 'red', 'green' ]
        - [ 'grapes', 'apple', 'chilli' ]
```

The above works correctly

But if I change the 2nd list to a dynamically generated list from the 1st list, it is not working. it throws `'item' is undefined"` error

Below is a rough implementation I'm trying and getting the error

```
    - name: color print - dynamic
      debug:
        msg:
        - "Copy from directory: {{ item[0] }} to {{ item[1] }}"
      with_nested:
        - [ 'red', 'green' ]
        - "{{colored_fuit| dictsort}}"
      vars:
        - color: "{{ item[0] }}"
        - colored_fuit:
            fruit1: "{{color}}_grapes"
            fruit2: "{{color}}_apple"
            fruit3: "{{color}}_chilli"
```

Why is it so? It is because the variable is not generated in case of 2nd list?

Comment: you have a self-referential set of `vars:`, where you are trying to define `colored_fruit:` but also `with_nested:` over them; it seems you need to move the `red, green` into a separate step and generate `colored_fruit:` in that step

Comment: The question doesn't make sense.  You can simply concatenate the items `"{{ item.0 }} to {{ item.0 }}_{{ item.1 }}"`.  I deleted the answer because I didn't know what you want. You commented: ``filter conditions from 1st list``. What is the condition? You commented: ``nesting needs to ensure the specific set only``. What is the expected specific set? I asked you to [edit] the question and make it [mre].

Answer (score 1):

use this piece of code to resolve your problem:

```
- name: color print - dynamic
  debug:
    msg: "Copy from directory: {{ item.0 }} to {{ item.0 }}_{{ item.1.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ color | product(colored_fuit|dictsort)|list }}"
  vars:
    color: [ 'red', 'green' ]
    colored_fuit:
        fruit1: "grapes"
        fruit2: "apple"
        fruit3: "chilli"
```

Comment: this is a great idea thanks for that. But my 2nd list is dependent on the 1st.

Comment: i dont understant by "dependent"... the result is a product of 2 lists, same result you want...

Comment: Unfortunately my 2nd list is dependent on the 1st list